# Shifting characters in a string to the left

Tags: java

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I have a lab question for a programming class that's been eluding me. The problem requires us to shift the elements of a string s to the left k times. For instance, if the input is "Hello World" and 3, it would output "lo WorldHel"). It also has to work relatively efficiently for very large values of k. This is what I have so far:

```
 String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int k){
   String result="";  

   for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
       result = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1) +s.charAt(0);

       s=result;
    }
    return s;
}
```

My major issue is that the last character of the original string keeps getting overwritten by the subsequent iterations of the loop. I've tried a great number of permutations, including converting the whole thing to arrays (which violates the efficiency restriction in the original problem). I feel like there's just a tiny thing I'm not getting, and I was wondering if someone could give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is to split the string at position `k` and merge both parts together again but in reverse order. 
The main problem is that `k` may be greater than or equal to the size of your string. So you need to bring `k` into a valid range again.

```
public static String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int k){
    k = k%s.length();
    return s.substring(k) + s.substring(0, k);
}
```

Testing the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test = "Hello World";
    for(int i = 0; i < test.length()*3; i++)
        System.out.println(cyclicLeftShift(test, i));
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
ello WorldH
llo WorldHe
lo WorldHel
o WorldHell
 WorldHello
WorldHello 
orldHello W
rldHello Wo
ldHello Wor
dHello Worl
Hello World
ello WorldH
llo WorldHe
lo WorldHel
o WorldHell
 WorldHello
WorldHello 
orldHello W
rldHello Wo
ldHello Wor
dHello Worl
Hello World
ello WorldH
llo WorldHe
lo WorldHel
o WorldHell
 WorldHello
WorldHello 
orldHello W
rldHello Wo
ldHello Wor
dHello Worl
```

Comment: This works perfectly and with relative efficiency. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one my boy:

```
String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int k) {

    String result = s.substring(k);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {

        result += s.charAt(i);

    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** will be thrown if your k is higher then your string length. For example, if your string is "Hello World" and k is 15.

Comment: Yes, I see. this method is only to shift valid count of k. This exception should check before calling this method. I think, the case of k is higher then the string should not execute. The programmer should reply error message for that case. So, I added no exception for it in this method. This catch should be in main. OK?

Comment: This one is the better approach.

Comment: The second loop can be replaces by another substring call.

Comment: Yes simon, it can be.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public static String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int k){
    String result=s;  

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
        result = result.substring(1) + result.charAt(0);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here's an example via [TutorialsPoint](http://goo.gl/5n2IRb). Just click on **compile** then **execute** to see the result.

Comment: In tut there is error while compiling. instead of shift you put shirt.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can you not just mod k by the length of s to get n (number of characters to shift), then take the substring of [0,n) and append it to the substring [n, s.length() -1]?

e.g.:

```
String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int k){
  String result="";
  int n = k % s.length();
  result = s.substring(n) + s.substring(0,n);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to String.substring() are (beginIndex, endIndex), NOT (beginIndex, count).  You need to pass s.length() instead of s.length()-1...  Or you could do it one of the much faster ways that others are posting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution is of help ! But it worked for me :) Well you could try it out!

```
 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Moving left by n characters");
    String str1 = moveCHaracters("Hellow World", 4);
    System.out.println(str1);
  }

  public static String moveCHaracters(String s, int k) {
    String result = s.substring(s.length() - (k));
    int length = s.length() - k;
    if (k > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result = result + s.charAt(i);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misake in the print statement , its moving left by N characters:)

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution, just need to take care that the **val** to be shifted must not be OutOfBounds.

```
String shiftLeft(String inp, int val)
{
     String shifted_str="";
     shifted_str=inp.substring(val);
     shifted_str+=inp.substring(0,val);
     return shifted_str;        
}
```